# UBER EATS API EXPO AUTHENTICATION USING EXPO

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, expo, uber-api

I'm new to expo and i've been trying to integrate the uber authentication to my app and i've tried the authentication example shown in the authentication page of expo documentation for uber.

Uber Example Authentication in expo documentation
https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#uber

And when I Login in browser I get an invalid_request.
I tried debugging the object and says my scopes are invalid, and i checked the documentation and the scopes are correct so idk how to solve this problem.
[The debug result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6RJ.png)

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I didn't need to identify the scopes because he would receive the authorization url with the scopes inside.